# Почему discord-бот выходит из онлайна?

Tags: python, discord.py, бот

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '(здесь токен моего бота)'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '!')

#!help

@client.event

async def on_ready():

    print ( 'Bot has connected' )

@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def hello( ctx ):

    await ctx.send( 'Bot greets you.' )

    #Connect

@bot.command(pass_context=True)  

async def test(ctx, arg):
 
    await ctx.send(arg)  

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

1. Бота очень сложно заставить появиться в онлайне, он «включается» только когда я запускаю файл с кодом, при закрытии файла он переходит в оффлайн. Каким образом можно сделать его независимым от меня?
2. Несмотря на все то, что написано в коде, он не выполняет никаких команд. Есть ли какие-то ресурсы, где даны списки команд для бота с примерами кодов?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Бот уходит в офлайн, потому что вы завершаете выполнение кода. Пока выполняется код - бот запущен и готов выполнять команды. Если вам нужно, чтобы бот оставался в онлайне, даже когда вы выключаете компьютер, то написанного бота нужно ставить на хостинг. Поищите сервисы в интернете. Это, естественно, не бесплатно.

**2.** Что касается выполнения команд, вы объявили в коде двух ботов. Одного с именем `client`, второго с именем `bot`. А по итогу запустили только второго: `bot.run(TOKEN)`

Строку `client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '!')`, я бы посоветовал убрать вообще и, поскольку он у вас не используется, все `@client` в коде заменить на `@bot`.

Ну и наконец, почему же именно не работают команды. `async def on_ready():` и `async def hello( ctx ):` у вас не вызываются, потому что, как я уже написал ранее, они привязаны к `@client`, которого вы не запускали. Если поменяете на `@bot`, то будут работать.

Для вызова функции вы указали префикс *"!"*, в этой строке `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`, соответственно вызов функции должен происходить следующим образом:

В чат пишете **[Префикс][Название функции] [Аргемунты]**. В вашем случае: `!test проверка`
На что бот должен отправить в чат "проверка".

А вообще это вы должны были узнать из [документации.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#extensions) Читайте, изучайте и подобных вопросов возникать не будет. Удачи :)

Comment: О втором: здесь проблема в том, что слушатель сообщений переписан, и не обрабатывает команды. Это настолько распространнёный вопрос, что указан в F.A.Q. в документации: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working. В остальном всё верно